# Complete a task from workflow

Tags: tasks, approval-process, approval, workflow-settings

In SharePoint Designer 2010 I'm trying to provide to an approval workflow two custom actions to avoid the 'open task, edit task, select approval value ,complete task' sequence so one action is for approval and the other for rejection.

Each custom action starts one workflow that changes the values of Approval value, %completion and task status but I cannot retrieve the value of the task since I'm not able to set the TaskOutcome anywhere.

Any ideas please? It's such a big headache working with SharePoint designer as it seems very limited.

Emilio.